# Messages I can't read at power off

Tags: shutdown

When I power off my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop there are 3 or lines of messages that flash up too fast to read before it shuts down. This didn't used to be the case. How can I establish what these messages say so I can address any underlying issues?

Comment: Same here bro @MitcheCA the line sometimes appears and when that lines doesn't display there is a logo of Ubuntu with a loading logo. But I noticed that the lines appears when I do some changes with commands in terminal or installed updates.

Comment: Managed to get a screenshot of Power Off Error Messages, they are:  

[482.712730] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout,switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x00170500  

[483.716719] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x00170500  

[484.720701] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x00170500  

None of which means much to me